# How do i run assets (npm run production) on an elastic beanstalk laravel application?

Tags: nginx, elastic-beanstalk, laravel, npm

I have a laravel application, running on an AWS eb instance (elastic beanstalk).I have uploded the code, and connected a database and everything works fine without any errors. But i need to compile some assets (for example tailwindcss, livewire...) so i need to run npm run production/npm run dev. my question is how do i do so, and if i even need to.

i tried to open a .ebextensions folder. in the folder i have a file named: build_assets.config.yaml, and in that file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    nodejs: [*]

container_commands:
  01_build_assets:
    command: "npm run prod"
```

and my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules"
},
```

i source bundled everything, uploded it again to eb and nothing changes, but throws no errors. the css looks all over the place because tailwindcss is not working... i also have a npm-shrinkwrap.json file, it did not contribute. would like to have some guidence, thank you!